# Can Solr retrieve values from children fields and associate the calculated value with the parent in result?

Tags: solr

I am using Solr for searching magento products in my project,
And i'm indexing Items(simple products) and products(configurable products),
I want to know, is it possible for solr to calculate and give back the price of a product based on the minimal price of its sub-products(items);

For instance, i have a product P1 and it is the parent of items m1, m2.
i need to get the minimal price from it items, and return it as a price of product P1.

I'm wondering if that is possible.
I need to know if solr can do that or if there is a feature or a way to do it ?
And finally i thank you!

for example:

```
{id = 1,
Name=p1,
Price=null,
}
{id = 2,
Name=m2,
Color=blue,
Price=30,
ParentId=1;
}
{id = 3,
Name=p1,
Color=blue,
Price=50,
parentId=1,
}
```

And If I seek for “p1” I want that p1 will be returned in the result with the price “30” .

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd either need to do this at during indexing :

Whenever you add a new child, re-index the parent having queried all of its children to find the lowest price.

Or with 2 queries at run time :

Get the parent, if price is null, get the min value of the children.

Comment: Thank you, in fact yes calculating price at index time is the most clean solution